# What is the easiest way to share photos in their original format?

Tags: google-photos, share-menu

My family in law has some wonderful pictures on their android phones. I'd like to use these in a printed photo album. Currently I only have the pictures at Whatsapp quality.

What would be the easiest way to exchange the original picture files?

Answer (score 2):

This question could have many solutions. I personally prefer cloud services for a bunch of reasons (based on personal experience) :

- Easy sharing, all you need to do is just share a link to the folder to where the photos are stored.
- Content upload /download can be tuned with configurable permission rights. This is useful to prevent accidental deletions.
- No loss in quality - original quality can be retained.
- Depending upon your privacy concerns, you can go with suitable cloud services or even host your own cloud.
- Some cloud services even offer cloud to cloud backup, so one need not be tied to the same cloud service. This also doubles up as cloud backup.
- Easy download to PC where pictures can be edited, sorted, categorised published.
- No need to download the entire library just to view. One can view them in cloud itself but the experience may be constrained (options to view such as slide shows may not be available - I haven't researched this).
- Offers client services on Android, Windows and other operating systems besides web based services that can be accessed through any web browser.
- Arguably cost effective.

These are some reasons that come immediately to my mind, since I am  heavily invested in similar activities, only difference being instead of photos, it is audio talks. I am no way related but the cloud service that meets our group needs best is [Pcloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pcloud.pcloud)